# Why does this recursive function only work when instantiating variable within the class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree

I am solving [this question on Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/range-sum-of-bst): Given the root node of a binary search tree, return the sum of values of all nodes with a value in the inclusive range [low, high].

My question is why does the function work when instantiating `running_sum` with `self` (snippet 1) but not when I keep track of `running_sum` in the function and use a return statement for `running sum` at the end of the function (snippet 2).

**Note:** I am just interested in understanding why the following code does work but the snippet afterwards does not, not the logic of the algorithm.

This works:

```
class Solution:
    
    def rangeSumBST(self, root: TreeNode, low: int, high: int) -> int:
        
        def helper(node):
            if low <= node.val <= high:
                self.running_sum += node.val
            
            if node.left and low < node.val:
                helper(node.left)
                
            if node.right and high > node.val:
                helper(node.right)
        
        self.running_sum = 0
        helper(root)
        return self.running_sum
```

This does not work:

```
class Solution:
    
    def rangeSumBST(self, root: TreeNode, low: int, high: int) -> int:
        
        def helper(node, running_sum):
            if low <= node.val <= high:
                running_sum += node.val
            
            if node.left and low < node.val:
                helper(node.left, running_sum)
                
            if node.right and high > node.val:
                helper(node.right, running_sum)
            
            return running_sum
        
        return helper(root,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case `running_sum` is a global variable for `helper`, so when

```
if low <= node.val <= high:
    running_sum += node.val
```

runs, it's added globaly.

In the second function `running_sum` is not stored globaly, so for this to work you need to replace

```
if ...:
    helper(..)
```

with

```
if ...:
    running_sum += helper(...)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just return the function early before getting to the recursive part?

Comment: not exactly, but I had an error and edited my answer maybe this will make more sense